# Switch Netgear XS748T does not detect link

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

I am having some issues setting up a switch in my lab. There is a 1-Gigabit ethernet line avalaible and I have a Netgear XS748T 48-port switch (only supports 1G and 10G ethernet links). Everything is disconnected. There is only one port connected to the building's network. The switch doesn't do anything. No led blinking, and it doesn't show up as a connected port in the management interface.

I have updated the firmware to the latest version (V6.5.1.59) and it doesn't improve.

I thought it might be a problem with the available link, so I have tested with another switch, a small 5-port TP-Link TL-SG105E (supports 10M/100M/1000M). If I connect this switch to the building's network (same cable), it works well. The LED of the corresponding port starts to blink in green (indicating a 1000M connection). In the web interface, it shows the port (autoconfigured) as 1000M full duplex.

That configuration actually works. If I connect some servers to the switch, they get their IP addresses and have internet connection. Of course, this is no solution because I need more than the 5 ports available on the small switch.

Any idea what might be the cause of the problem? If the small switch detects the links as a full duplex gigabit connection, why is the Netgear XS748T not able to do the same?

PS: I know one possible solution could be to chain both switches, but I'd like to use only the Netgear XS748T if possible.

Comment: Does the Netgear actually work when connected to the TP-Link?

Comment: Yes, the Netgear works when connected to the TP-Link. And the servers can get IP through DHCP when connected to the Netgear in that way: server -> Netgear -> TP-Link -> (building's network)

Comment: Yes, when I've tried chaining both switches is LAN port to LAN port. The link between them is detected as 1-gigabit by both devices.

Comment: @John: They're switches, they don't even have LAN/WAN ports?

Comment: I think @user1686 is right, all the ports are the same in both devices.

Comment: Do the switches have the "cable test" feature?

Comment: Yes, if I run the "cable test" with the TP-Link, the test result is "normal" and the "Cable Fault Distance(m)" is 1. The Netgear also reports as "normal", but does not give any cable length nor failure.

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly same issue within our network, thought the switch defective initially..
But after trying couple of methods, we got a conclusion that the switch has an issue with link negotiation.

If you have any laptop with an Ethernet port you can adjust the link speed to 1Gbps from auto, this will connect right away.
The default setting would be auto negotiation.
Of course the cable should be something like Cat6e not Cat5e.